# how to remove index.php from url cakephp

Tags: cakephp, url-rewriting

i have build a webapp on Cakephp 2.3 .. on my locaLhost all urls were fine.. i can access my urls like this

```
http://localhost/Cakephp
```

but now when i have uploaded the site on server in root folder ... i cant access my url like this

```
http://www.myweb.com
```

instead it can accessible like this

```
http://www.myweb.com/index.php/login
```

what i think that might be a problem is the .htaccess file in my app/webroot folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

I think this kind of index.php is causing the problem ..as i dont know about .htaccess so dont know how to remove it.

How do I get index.php out of my urls?

Comment: What you describe means that mod_rewrite isn't enabled - which also probably means that your host has disabled `.htaccess` files. You can't solve this without modifying your apache config, which on a shared host (are you on a shared host?) will almost certainly not be possible.

Answer (score 3):

#### So, it should be ok? You already have mod_rewrite?

If `mod_rewrite` is correctly loaded, `.htaccess` files are in place and `index.php` still appears in links then it is most probably problem with `core.php` framework configuration file.

#### Problem cause

In my case it was problem with `App.baseUrl` configuration option:

```php
Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

#### Solving problem

Here is how I fixed that problem (and few others with redirects) by commenting out following line from `core.php`:

```php
// Configure::write('App.baseUrl', env('SCRIPT_NAME'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check the `mod_rewrite` module is installed or not? if not kindly enable it in `httpd.conf` file.

Find the following line and remove `#` (means uncomment) in front of it.

```
 LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

Also don't forget to restart apache http service using following command:

```
 service httpd restart
```

Following are the steps to edit http.conf file from CPanel:

1. Log in to WHM/cPanel as the root user.
2. Open the "Service Configuration" section.
3. Open the "Apache Configuration" section.
4. Click "Global Configuration" to access the httpd.conf's settings, as displayed through cPanel.
5. Make your desired changes, then click the "Save" button. This saves the changes and then reboots Apache so that the changes are applied.

Read more: http://www.ehow.com/how_8696084_edit-httpdconf-cpanel.html#ixzz2YRDEgOMT

On IIS Server [Read this link to enable mod_rewrite](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/filippo.toso/2008/01/29/cakephp-on-iis)

Comment: HOw to i enable it ? where do i find the mod_rewrite option ?

Comment: how can i access the httpd.conf file? where it would be ?

Comment: You will find httpd.conf file at /usr/local/apache/conf directory. Check this link: http://www.ehow.com/how_8696084_edit-httpdconf-cpanel.html

Comment: i have uploaded my site to  Windows server running IIS

Comment: You should look into this link: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-the-url-rewrite-module

Comment: There is some problems with cakephp (_I'll bet it's incorrect configuration_) inserting `//domain.tld/index.php/controller/action` to link URLs. Sometimes it could even end up being `//domain.tld/index.php/index.php/controller/action`. This problem has came up with `mod_rewrite` loaded and fully functional and it actually seems that URL is not cleaned up correctly (_for cakephp_) while apache is rewriting with mod_rewrite. It could also be that cakephp interprets rewritten URL unexpected way (_users might just expect too much "autocorrection" from framework :)_).

Answer (score 0):

on ubuntu,

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```